# Possible to search/replace AND swap positions of values in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

Is it possible to use a query to swap positions of characters within the SAME value/column?

Example, I have a large table with a column that lists sizes like so:

```
12x24 Bulletin

7x14 Bulletin

14x48 Bulletin, etc.
```

The problem is now my boss has decided that he wants it to read:

```
Bulletin 12x24

Bulletin 7x14

Bulletin 14x48
```

Is it possible to swap those positions with a query or a regular expression? Or do I have to go manually update each record (very time consuming as there aprrox. 500 records to be modified)? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Your best bet is to write a script that extracts them into two separate columns, so you can display them however you want.

Comment: Generally text manipulation on this scale in mysql requires a custom stored procedure or function and a lot of work.  However, in this case, you could use one code block to `LIKE` 'Bulletin', another to `REPLACE` ' Bulletin' with blank and a third to `CONCAT` 'Bulletin '.  But doing a full regex search/replace isn't really possible with mysql unfortunately.  (just match, not replace)

Comment: Do you need to permamently replace these values in the table or only dynamically replace them at query time in certain cases? In other words are you looking for a SELECT statement that can do this or an UPDATE statement to modify the data (or possibly even populate into two columns which it seems might be appropriate).

Comment: @mike, these would need to be permanently replaced so i suppose the UPDATE statement is the way to modify.

Comment: @ebyrob i was afraid of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

The "trick" is to write an expression that returns the new value to be assigned.

It looks like you could achieve what you want by finding occurrences of `' Bulletin'` and replacing that with an empty string, and pre-pending the remaining value with `'Bulletin '`.

Here's a demonstration...

```
-- test cases
CREATE TABLE foo (id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, mycol VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO foo (mycol) VALUES ('12x24 Bulletin'),('7x14 Bulletin'),('14x48 Bulletin')

-- test expression to return new value to be assigned
SELECT mycol AS oldval
     , CONCAT('Bulletin ',REPLACE(mycol,' Bulletin','')) AS newval
  FROM foo
 WHERE mycol LIKE '% Bulletin%'

-- use that expression in an UPDATE statement to replace the value 
UPDATE foo 
   SET mycol = CONCAT('Bulletin ',REPLACE(mycol,' Bulletin',''))
 WHERE mycol LIKE '% Bulletin%'
```

---

There are some gotchas to be aware of in the UPDATE statement, such as referencing a column in an expression after it's assigned a value. (Not a problem in the example I gave above, but it can be in the more general case.

Note: The MySQL REGEXP operator returns a boolean, not a string function, so, no, you can't "use a regular expression" to return a replacement value. You could use REGEXP in place the LIKE operator in the examples above.

---

### FOLLOWUP

The above assumes you want to update the values stored in a table. If you only want to do the modification at the time you pull the data, you could use an expression in the SELECT list, similar to the above.

```
INSERT INTO foo (mycol) VALUES ('Stapler 12')

SELECT IF(mycol LIKE '% Bulletin'
         ,CONCAT('Bulletin ',REPLACE(mycol,' Bulletin',''))
         ,mycol
       ) AS mycol
  FROM foo
```

Comment: Wow what a complete explanation. This response in conjunction with ebyrob's has been very educational. Thank you for taking the time two write this all out. My problem has been solved and I'm learning so much. I knew of regexp's and knew they had somewhat limited funcionality in the scope internal to mysql. Also with this example, if my boss decides to swap any more data on me I can choose to do it per display or permanently. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Is it always a whitespace between this two values? If yes, you can select your records like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, ' ', -1),' ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, ' ', 1)) AS value FROM tableName
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a04d8d/6

Table schema for this query I used:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (
 id int auto_increment primary key, 
 details varchar(30));

INSERT INTO tableName (id, details)
VALUES (NULL,'12x24 Bulletin'), (NULL,'7x14 Bulletin');
```

Comment: Nice use of `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.  Definitely don't know that one well enough to have a handle on negative indexes etc.  Would this, for instance, double the string up when there's no space in it?  (Thanks to your sqlfiddle, yes.  yes it would)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what seems natural to me, though not too flexible:

```
UPDATE SOMETABLE
SET SOMECOLUMN = CONCAT('Bulletin ', REPLACE(SOMECOLUMN, ' Bulletin', ''))
WHERE SOMECOLUMN LIKE '% Bulletin'
;
```

Comment: +1. It took me longer to write my answer, but this is exactly the same approach I took, although I allowed characters following `' Bulletin'`. Depends what should be done in the case of `'1x2 Bulletin foo'`

Comment: @spencer7593 Given the problem description, I think the most strict selection criteria is appropriate.  If something isn't expected, modifying it could be a problem.  (Though your idea of using `REGEX` in the `WHERE` clause I like)

Comment: There is no whitespace after Bulletin. This worked beautifully. Thank you @ebyrob, you saved me from having to manually update each record individually! I am learning so much from stackoverflow, you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If those examples hold true, then you can do the swapping by doing:

```
update t
    set col = ws_concat(' ', substring_index(col, ' ', -1), substring_index(col, ' ', 1)
    where col like '% Bulletin';
```

Alternatively, you could just do this when you query on the column:

```
select ws_concat(' ', substring_index(col, ' ', -1), substring_index(col, ' ', 1) as size,
       <other columns
from t;
```

However, the existence of the problem suggests that you are stuffing two types of information into a single column.  You should consider having two columns -- in your case, one would contain `'Bulletin'` (some sort of "sizetype" column) and another would have the dimensions.  You might even want to split the dimensions into additional columns.

Actually, as I write this, I suspect that you are missing an *entity* in your database.  This column should actually be a foreign key to a `sizes` table.  That table would have one row per size thingee.  You can then have various columns for representing the size to suite you, your boss, your boss's boss, or whoever.

Comment: Amen to mixed info, but...  Almost certainly `Bulletin` is not really an informative string so much as type information  (At worst: Just being in the table may be enough to indicate it!).  Come to think of it 12x24 is two pieces of information that should be split.

Comment: yes, i know: in my opinion it really shouldn't matter if it says "1x1 bulletin" or "bulletin 1x1", but apparently this is important to the boss. in this case, unfortunatel making separate columns doesn't fit the scheme of how our products work. for example, bulletins are all in thier own category while things like posters and bench signs are in their own category as well.